# Неправильно работает счетчик времени на vue js

Tags: vue.js, счетчики

как сделать правильно счетчик чтобы отсчитывал сколько осталось времени до конца аренды.

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name:'order',

  data()
  {
    
    return{order:{},currentTime:null,timer:null,time:""}
  },
  
  created()
  {
    this.showOrder()
  },
  mounted()
  {
    this.inDate()
    this.startTimer()
  },
  destroyed()
  {
    this.stopTimer()
  },
  methods:
  {
    inDate()
    {
      let dateNow = new Date()
    let insec1 = dateNow / 1000 // Переводим дату в секунды
    let NachDate = new Date(this.order["dateEnd"])
    let insec2 = NachDate / 1000 // переводим дату следующего сообщения в секунды.
    this.currentTime= insec2 - insec1
    },
    showOrder()
    {
    axios({method:"get",url:'../php/orderCar.php?action=showOrder',responseType:"json"}).then(response=>{this.order=response.data})
    },
    startTimer()
    {
      let dateNow=new Date()
      let sec1=dateNow/1000
       this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.currentTime--
        let sec=this.currentTime
       var h = sec/3600 ^ 0 ;
                    var d=sec/86400;
                    var m = (sec-h*3600)/60 ^ 0 ;
                    var s = sec-h*3600-m*60 ;
                    this.time = (d<10?"0"+m:m)+" дн. "+(m<10?"0"+m:m)+" мин. "+(s<10?"0"+s:s)+" сек.";

      }, 1000)
    },
    stopTimer()
    {
       clearTimeout(this.timer)
    },
    
  },
  watch:
  {
    currentTime(time)
    {
      if (time===0)
      {
        this.stopTimer()
      }
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

код взял отсюда:
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071878/laravel-vue-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/1159139#1159139)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что в нем конкретно работает неправильно? Приведите воспроизводимый код

Comment: На фотографии NaN пишется или вообще в отрицательные значения секунды уходят. Такое ощущение что он не присваивает разницу секунд в переменную currentTime

Answer (score 0):

Как сделать чтобы время отображал в 24 часовом формате

```
var d=sec/86400 ^0;
                   var h = sec/3600 ^ 0 ;
                      var m = (sec-h*3600)/60 ^ 0 ;
                     var s = sec-h*3600-m*60 ^0;
                 this.time = (d<10?"0"+d:d)+" дн. "+(h<10?"0"+h:h)+" ч. "+(m<10?"0"+m:m)+" мин. "+(s<10?"0"+s:s)+" сек.";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]